# Should there be a linear force acting aside from torque?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Assume to identical motors are placed vertically on-top of a table and they are not fixed able to move/fall etc...and they have gears attached to them and are attached to one another like this image:

[image]

Now, I powered both motors, and the torques of the two are the same and opposing one another as illustrated here:

[image]

OR:

[image]

What I think would intuitively happen due to the two torques($t_1$ & $t_2$) being the same and opposing one another is that the rotors/gears would be at rest. However, is there a form of linear force acting on the motors? Due to them opposing one another would that cause the first or second motor to fall from the table due to a unknown linear force?

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass of each motor will move in accordance with the sum of all forces acting on the entire subsystem (motor plus rotor). This means that the motors will indeed move - they are "pushing away" from each other in the same way that one of them would move if it tried to spin its rotor against, say, a wall or a floor. Put your picture on its side, replace one rotor with a solid surface, and it looks like you are looking at half a car... what happens if the engine in the car starts driving the wheel?

The same thing happens here.

Comment: But how are they pushing away from each other? The rotors are at rest because they oppose one another, how would that create a form of linear force that moves the motor itself?

Comment: Maybe that it's due to the reaction force(Newtons 3rd law)?

Comment: How does a car start moving when it is at rest and it tries to move its wheels? Yes, it is the reaction force. Note that the motors will spin in a direction opposite to the motion of the rotors if they are not connected to anything.

Comment: AH! I forgot, if the motors are stuck (rotors net torque) the bottom part will rotate. I remembered once i held motor's rotor and they motor can move freely, the motor itself rotated! Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Then technically, there is no linear force(pushing the motor forward backward(x,z axis) there is only a rotational force that acts on the motor in the y-axis the reaction torque?

Comment: Nope. If you had a single motor + rotor, one would spin clockwise and the other counterclockwise, with a net angular momentum of zero. As it is, there _is_ a net force on each rotor/motor pair, so they _will_ move away from each other. In the process they (the pair of motors) will end up with a net angular momentum, and this is compensated for by the fact that the individual motor/rotor combinations will have angular momentum that opposes that. See [this interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdq4wer7vgk) around 2:40 - 3:00 is particularly interesting in this context.

Comment: Imagine instead of a table as diagramed above, lets say each motor took an individual cart that is moveable. So exactly the same set-up however, instead of a table its more of a moveable cart. The motors being fixed to their individuals carts(1&2) will the carts feel any force forward/backward from the motors? Or any side ways force right/left?